# overriding Devise::Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I'm trying to add a method to Devise::Mailer, the method should send mail to a user with a link to set his own password when an admin creates a new user without password.

```
Devise::Mailer.class_eval do
  def set_password_instructions(record)
    setup_mail(record, :set_password_instructions)
  end
end
```

If I put this in /lib and require it in application.rb it gets loaded before the real Devise.
If I require it in top of my user.rb it works for the first time, fails with unknown method set_password_instructions any other time.

It only works when I add the above code directly in `user#send_set_password_instructions`

user.rb:

```
  def send_set_password_instructions
    Devise::Mailer.class_eval do
      def set_password_instructions(record)
        setup_mail(record, :set_password_instructions)
      end
    end

    generate_reset_password_token!
    ::Devise.mailer.set_password_instructions(self).deliver
  end
```

Can someone shed some light on this weird behavior?
It looks like Devise.mailer reloads Devise::Mailer class?